# android Lollipop. Notifications not working

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notifications

Faced with the problem of displaying notifications in android Lollipop. When app is open notifications shows app fine, but when the application is closed they are not displaying. On 4x versions of android everything works properly. Here is a method to display them

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void sendNotification(String body, String title, String badge) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("from_notify", true);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, Integer.valueOf(badge), intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setShowWhen(true)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: I checked your code on my lollipop device and it works perfectly fine. Tested in both cases launching from activity and from broadcast receiver. To make sure the activity is dead the receiver responds to the BOOT action. So the problem is elsewhere. May I ask what is the manufacturer of your test device? Some manufacturers make some additional "app optimizations". For example for Huawei it literally force stops your app so no broadcast receiver will work and this would match described behaviour. Remember that "force stop" disables your app until restarted from launcher.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem:

when your app is closed,all app's data will be cleared including the notifications and statics data,so if you want to make notifications alive all the time you have to send it from service(create service class and run it in the background).

try this:

```
public class YourService extends Service {
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //send your notifications here
    return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

note that you can send notifications from other classes not just from service class,but you have to run a service in the background because it helps to keep statics data for your app after it is closed.this worked for me.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This is not true. Only ongoing notifications require service backing it. Regular notifications like the one in the question can be launched from anywhere.

Comment: just i told you that (i think),i did not work with lolipop, i wish  you find the answer quickly,good luck.